# como fazer uma solicitação POST?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

É o seguinte, estou usando o api do google para montar um app. Porem cheguei nessa parte abaixo e não consigo de jeito nenhum. Como faço esse POST q ele me pede? Ja tenho todos os dados de parametro.

Abaixo o trecho da ajuda do google:

```
Supondo que o usuário tenha acesso a seu aplicativo, troque o código de autorização recebido na etapa 3 por um toque de atualização e um token de acesso. Envie uma solicitação POST para https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token

Veja um exemplo de solicitação abaixo:

POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: accounts.google.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

    code=4/ux5gNj-_mIu4DOD_gNZdjX9EtOFf&
    client_id=1084945748469-eg34imk572gdhu83gj5p0an9fut6urp5.apps.googleusercontent.com&
    client_secret=hDBmMRhz7eJRsM9Z2q1oFBSe&
    redirect_uri=http://localhost/oauth2callback&
    grant_type=authorization_code
```

E esse POST era pra me retornar o seguinte:

```
{
  "access_token" : "ya29.AHES6ZTtm7SuokEB-RGtbBty9IIlNiP9-eNMMQKtXdMP3sfjL1Fc",
  "token_type" : "Bearer",
  "expires_in" : 3600,
  "refresh_token" : "1/HKSmLFXzqP0leUihZp2xUt3-5wkU7Gmu2Os_eBnzw74"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supondo que os dados que você vai enviar estejam em uma variável chamada `data`:

```
var data = {
  code : "4/ux5gNj-_mIu4DOD_gNZdjX9EtOFf&",
  client_id :" 1084945748469-eg34imk572gdhu83gj5p0an9fut6urp5.apps.googleusercontent.com&",
  client_secret" : "hDBmMRhz7eJRsM9Z2q1oFBSe&",
  redirect_uri : "http://localhost/oauth2callback&",
  grant_type="authorization_code"
}

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', '/my/url', true);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
request.send( data );
```

Referência: [You might not need jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)

Comment: Blz, vou fazer um teste. Como guardo os parametros na variavel data? Posso fazer data = 'parametros?'

Comment: Vou editar a resposta com essas instruções.

Comment: Vlw cara, enviou. Porem deu esse erro: XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400. O q pode ser?

Comment: Esse erro significa que o servidor que está recebendo o seu post não está configurado para receber requisições do endereço localhost. Nesse caso a solução varia de acordo com a API ou serviço para o qual você quer mandar.